# NSDateFormatter returning null, but was working just fine before

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I had this code work for a while, but it stopped working, and this always returns null, although date is valid. Here is code and output:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSLog(@"date - %@, formatted date - %@", self.date, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.date]);

date - 2013-09-02 10:00:00, formatted date - (null)
```

Comment: for me the above code is working, so it seems that there must be any problem in self.date.Could you please provide self.date.

Comment: try to change the dataformat i.e the self.date is in the yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss but you have used different format . Try to change the format

Comment: Are you sure `self.date` is a `NSDate` object? Show us how you initialize it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

Output:

```
2013-09-04 10:51:10.681 Untitled[753:707] date - 2013-09-04 08:51:10 +0000, formatted date - 10:51 04.09.2013
```

I used:

```
NSLog(@"date - %@, formatted date - %@", [NSDate date], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

So there must be something with your self.date. You can explain or paste more code with self.date.

Comment: It was string in nsdate object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try like this:-
The problem is your self.date was not converting it into proper date format:
here assuming your self.date was string object

    NSDate *convertIntoDate=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:self.date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSLog(@"date - %@, formatted date - %@", self.date, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:convertIntoDate]);
```

Comment: what is the method dateWithNaturalLanguageString? I get unrecognized selector.

Comment: + (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string              It creates and returns an NSDate object set to the date and time specified by a given string. So i assumed that self.date was string instance.